# How to configure GCR with K3S

Tags: google-container-registry, k3s

Trying to set up Google container registry (GCR) with k3s according to the documentation - Private Registry Configuration
https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/private-registry/

I keep getting 401 Unauthorized error when running the command `crictl pull gcr.io/my-project-id/my-image:latest`

```
WARN[2022-06-08T14:36:38.338217895+03:00] image connect using default endpoints: [unix:///run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock unix:///run/crio/crio.sock]. As the default settings are now deprecated, you should set the endpoint instead. 
FATA[2022-06-08T14:36:40.739055570+03:00] pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "gcr.io/my-project-id/my-image:latest": failed to resolve reference "gcr.io/my-project-id/my-image:latest": pulling from host gcr.io failed with status code [manifests latest]: 401 Unauthorized
```

here is my config: `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml`

```
mirrors:
  gcr.io:
    endpoint:
      - "https://gcr.io"
configs:
  "gcr.io":
    auth:
     username: _json_key
     password: |
      {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "my-project-id",
        "private_key_id": "4c97dc266e4b303fc45dc70561e383ae92ccccae",
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXIEvAIBADANB........\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        "client_email": "build@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_id": "108884742074047075648",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/build%40my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      }
```

Comment: The syntax from above works, a restart was required. thanks to  @Richie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't see it anywhere in the documentation, but I took for granted that the password should be a single line. I suppose I got to that conclusion because is the way I configured it in CI/CD pipelines. Anyway, just convert your password to a single quoted line and you are done (I have tried myself):

```
mirrors:
  gcr.io:
    endpoint:
      - "https://gcr.io"
configs:
  "gcr.io":
    auth:
     username: _json_key
     password: '{"type": "service_account", "project_id": "my-project-id", "private_key_id": "4c97dc266e4b303fc45dc70561e383ae92ccccae", "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXIEvAIBADANB........\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "client_email": "build@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "client_id": "108884742074047075648", "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs", "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/build%40my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}'
```

Then restart k3s.

Please, note you will need to add the `registries.yaml` file to all your k3s agent nodes and also to your k3s server nodes in case you deploy workloads in them.

Hope this help.

Comment: the restart was the missing part, the syntax with pipe is also valid